# Writing cells to table Performance

Tags: matlab

i am adding rows to a table within a loop.
For each row I add each cell individually.

```
for ki = 1:end;
 table.v1(i)    = {val1(1)};
 table.v2(i)    = {val2(1)};
 table.v2(i)    = {mean(val3};
 table.v4(i)    = {mean(val4};
end
```

This also gives me the warning message:

*Warning: The assignment added rows to the table, but did not assign values to all of the
 table's existing variables. Those variables have been extended with rows containing default
 values.*

I have set warnings off to stop cluttering the output.

```
warning('off','all');
```

Is this much slower than concatenating all values to a row and then adding the entire row to the table?